# SQLiteOpenHelper vs ContentProvider

Tags: android, sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

I'm new to Android development. I'm trying to create an application that reads from the internal database (SQLite) and list all the data in a list (I'm using `listView`).

So far I got a class called `DatabaseHandler` that extends `SQLiteOpenHelper` and that is doing all the database operations (select data, insert data, delete data, ...).

But now that I want to list the values, I am reading in some websites that I have to use a `Loader` instead of `Cursor`, and therefore a `ContentProvider`. So far I understand that `ContentProvider` provides controlled access to the database.

My question is: does the `ContentProvider` do the same as `SQLiteOpenHelper`?

Also, I'm using API level 8 and the `ContentProvider` is only available on API level 11. What is the best way to solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can't answer on the *best* way, but the *pragmatic* way is to use a Cursor. It still works perfectly well, and you save a lot of development time if you don't need the additional features provided by the ContentProvider.

Comment: @Heinzi It would be good to use Cursor as they seem simpler. The problem is that when using `startmanagingcursor(cursor)` it says it's deprecated. Also I keep reading that loaders are better due to the data synchronization issues...

Comment: [SQLiteOpenHelper is a helper class intended to use within ContentProvider](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html)

Comment: `Also, I'm using API level 8 and the ContentProvider is only available on API level 11. What is the best` not true ... `Loader`s are from API 11 but we have support library v4 ... `ContentProvider`s are from API 1 :)

Comment: You're right! I totally mixed them up! :P So the best solution is to use support libraries?

Answer (score 10):

> My question is: does the ContentProvider do the same as
>   SQLiteOpenHelper?

`ContentProvider` is implemented by application's developer if he or she would allow other developers to access to application's database in their application - simply put for *sharing*. It's like a server of some database and it's client is `ContentResolver` who knows `ContentProvider`'s authority. For example if you need to get some contacts from your device, than you should use `ContentProvider` of Contacts database and more concretely it's [Contract classes](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.html).

If you know an authority of appropriate `ContentProvider` you may comunicate with it using a `ContentResolver` object.

In other cases you should interact with database through SQL abstract model which is represented by [`android.database`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/package-summary.html) and [`android.database.sqlite`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/package-summary.html) classes.

And also - `ContentProvider` available from the primary API level as one of the main component of application.

## Update

From the official documentation:

> Before you start building a provider, do the following:
>
> > Decide if you need a content provider. You need to build a content
> >     provider if you want to provide one or more of the following features:
> >
> > You want to offer complex data or files to other applications.
> >
> > You want to allow users to copy complex data from your app into other apps.
> >
> > You want to provide custom search suggestions using the search framework.

Comment: This is the main purpose of `ContentProvider` - to export it to other applications. If you don't need to export your data to another applications than you shouldn't consider to use `ContentProvider`.

Comment: No... main purpose is [to manage access to a structured set of data](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html)(i don't see single "export" word there). I can even say ... this is prefered way of accesing data(even SQLite) on android!

Comment: In my case I don't want to export to other applications. I just want to access database data internally and list it. The problem is that when I am trying to use `Cursor` and `startmanagingcursor(cursor)`, it says that this is deprecated and that I should replace it by a Loader. And as far as I know, a Loader needs a `ContentProvider`, that's why I am confused...

Comment: Edited my answer for better explanation basing on official documentation

Comment: So what should I do if I don't want to use ContentProvider (because I don't need it) but I want to list all the data in the database?

Comment: if you wana: **no auto requery support, cursors leaking, sqlopenhelper leak, manual guarding for multiple threads access to db, no Loaders support** then **you can use plain SQLite** ...

Comment: Intention of `ContentProvider` was to serve data to other processes via a defined interface. But things changed with Honeycomb. All the deprecated methods like `startManagingCursor` tell you to use a Loader now. A `CursorLoader` does not work without a `ContentProvider` and `Uri` based change notifications that cause automatic reloading in a background thread (#1 reason for Loaders) won't work either. There are probably ways around but `ContentProvider` is definitely the way you should consider now. also http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/07/loaders-and-loadermanager-background.html

Comment: So I guess I need a `ContentProvider` then... Thanks a lot for your answers! :)

Answer (score 9):

`SQLiteOpenHelper` is used to manage database creation and open. It is only a helper class for sqlite database and could be used in anywhere with db operation.

`ContentProvider` is one of the 4 basic components of android, the other 3 are `Activity`, `Service` and `Broadcast`. `ContentProvider` is used to manage access to any structured data set, including sqlite database. The data source of `ContentProvider` could be a databse but not have to be.

`ContentProvider` is often used in providing own data to others applications, just like `ContactsProvider` and `CalendarProvider`. And it is more safe to provide some specified interface using `ContentProvider`, compared with providing a database directly.